# Create dropdowns based on previous dropdown chosen value

Tags: angular

I have a json file which i am getting through some service and then populating it in my dropdowns. The first dropdown is bank name which is populating correctly but for second and third dropdown where i want to populate city and branch name is not working .It is only populating the cities name for the first bank and the same for the branches.
I have added my json file and component.ts file where i have used that logic

bankdetails.json

```
{
    "banks": {
        "SBI": {
            "cities": {
                "Bangalore": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }

                    }
                },"Hyderabad": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "CBI": {
            "cities": {
                "pune": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                },"chennai": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "HDFC": {
            "cities": {
                "Bangalore": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                },"Hyderabad": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "BOI": {
            "cities": {
                "Bangalore": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                },"Hyderabad": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "IDFC": {
            "cities": {
                "Bangalore": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                },"Hyderabad": {
                    "branches": {
                        "rrnamgar1": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100000"

                        },
                        "rrnamgar2": {
                            "ifsc" : "SBIN100001"

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.banks = this.modalservice.returnBankList();
    this.cities = this.banks[Object.keys(this.banks)[0]];
    this.citiesname = this.cities[Object.keys(this.cities)[0]];
    this.branches = this.citiesname[Object.keys(this.citiesname)[0]];
    this.branchnames = this.branches[Object.keys(this.branches)[0]];

}

firstDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = Object.keys(this.banks);
    console.log(obj, val);



    if (obj != null && val !== -1) {
        this.city = Object.keys(this.cities["cities"]);

        console.log("cities are " + this.city);
    }

}
secondDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.city;
    console.log(val, obj);

    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj != null && val !== -1) {
        this.branch = Object.keys(this.branches["branches"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom pipe for this. I personally try and avoid custom pipes in general, since they can be costly if it needs to be impure, and rather modify the data as such that we can use it as we like, so in other words, do the "work" in the component.

So in this case I would first modify your data to such that it's iterable, so make `banks` an array, and in each bank have a property `cities`, which contains an array with each city belonging to that bank with property `branches` that contains all branches belonging to that specific city.

So your component code for doing this, would look like this:

```ts
// call this method after receiving your data
modifyBanks() {
  // banksArr contains your JSON
  this.banksArr = this.transform(banks.banks, 'bank', 'cities');
  this.banksArr.forEach(bank => {
    bank.cities = this.transform(bank.cities, 'city', 'branches')
    bank.cities.forEach(city => {
      city.branches = this.transform(city.branches, 'branch', 'ifsc')
    })
  })
}


transform(value, str1, str2) {
  let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(value),
    dataArr = [];
    keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
      dataArr.push({[str1]: key, [str2]: value[key][str2]});
    });
    return dataArr;
}
```

Your template would look like the following, where we use `ngModel` together with `ngValue` to bind the whole object:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="bank">
  <option [ngValue]="bank" *ngFor="let bank of banksArr">
    {{bank.bank}}
  </option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="city">
  <option [ngValue]="city" *ngFor="let city of bank?.cities">
    {{city.city}}
  </option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="branch">
  <option [ngValue]="branch" *ngFor="let branch of city?.branches">
    {{branch.branch}} 
  </option>    
</select>
```

**DEMO**: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6reieb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi AJT_82. When i ran the code with the changes you suggested I got error in console .

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at IDFCModalComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/payment/modal/modal.component.ts.IDFCModalComponent.transform (modal.component.ts:60)
    at IDFCModalComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/payment/modal/modal.component.ts.IDFCModalComponent.ngOnInit (modal.component.ts:45)

Comment: when i am consoling the value field in the transform method it's giving me undefined

Comment: it's working fine now but I am not able to access ifsc from that .I have to capture that ifsc from the last forEach statement.

Comment: I am trying this code city.branches.forEach(branch => {
   this.ifsccode = branch.ifsc;  ,but in this case I am always getting the ifsc of the second branch eevn if i am selecting first branch from the dropdown